# Ayuda en una lista en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Este es el fragmento de mi código:

```
public static void Lista(String textList) { 
        String[]stList= textList.split(",");
          Arrays.asList(stList);
              for(int i = 0; i < stList.length; i++){
          System.out.println("Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: ");
                  if((stList == null) || (stList.equals(""))){
                      System.out.println(" El campo que ingreso esta vacio, vuelva a ingresarlo");
                  }else{
                    System.out.println(stList[i]);
              }
        }
    }
```

Es una lista, la cual estoy tratando con los comando If y Else que me indique que el campo este vació y que este vuelva a mostrar el mensaje: "Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: "

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu error, podrías ser más específico?

Comment: Tomas un String, lo vuelves un Array y ese Array lo conviertes en una List. a) Cuando haces `asList`, no guardas el resultado en ninguna variable. b) cuando le pides un input al usuario, no estás recibiendo nada (con un Scanner, por ejemplo) y es raro que lo pidas **dentro** del ciclo for. Revisa la lógica de lo que deseas hacer y con gusto te ayudamos con los problemas que tengas.

Comment: Hola, es que en la lista no ingreso nada la cual espero que me salga el mensaje:"El campo que ingreso esta vació, vuelva a ingresarlo" Pero este no aparece y termina mi programa. También desearía que me ayudaran a que me vuelva a solicitar: "Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: ". Por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que en tu código no entra al `if` ya que estas comparando todo el `array` a *null* se debio de haber comparado con la posición en la que esta iterando el ciclo así: `stList[i]`, si deseas que te vuelva a pedir la cadena lo puedes hacer dentro de un ciclo `while`, adaptando un poco tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
private static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = ""
    String continuar = "Si";
    //Se hace un ciclo para volver a pedir la cadena a evaluar.
    while(continuar.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
        //Se pide el string por teclado que se va a pasar al método.
        System.out.println("Ingrese una cadena: ");
        s = teclado.nextLine();
        Lista(s);
        System.out.println("Desea continuar?: Si/No ");
        continuar = teclado.nextLine();
    }

}

public static void Lista(String textList) {
    String[] stList = textList.split(",");
    Arrays.asList(stList);
    for (int i = 0; i < stList.length; i++) {
        //Pregunto si la posición esta vacía
        if (stList[i] == null || stList[i].trim().equals("")) {
            //Si esta vacia pido el nuevo valor a tomar en la posición
            System.out.println("El campo que ingreso esta vacio, vuelva a ingresarlo");
            stList[i] = teclado.nextLine();
            //Regreso la posición de i en 1 para que imprima el nuevo valor introducido a la posición
            i = i-1;
        } else {
            System.out.println(stList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias me funciono.

Comment: Hola, una pregunta: ¿Como puedo hacer que me detecte el carácter ","? por ejemplo que no ingrese la coma y que me salga un mensaje: "no ingreso el carácter: ',' vuelva a ingresarlo".

Comment: Puedes verificar la letra con el método `contains(",")` y en caso de no ser así que vuelva a pedir la palabra.