# Problemas con un Bucle

Tags: java

Hola anteriormente me ayudaron con esta parte de mi código:

```
   public static void Lista(String textList) { 
        String[]stList= textList.split(",");
          Arrays.asList(stList);
              for(int i = 0; i < stList.length; i++){
          System.out.println("Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: ");
                  if((stList == null) || (stList.equals(""))){
                      System.out.println(" El campo que ingreso esta vacio, vuelva a ingresarlo");
                  }else{
                    System.out.println(stList[i]);
              }
        }
    }
```

La cual ahora tengo este pequeño detalle: quisiera que la sentencia `if(toList.contains(","))` se repita cada vez que no se inserte la coma (,). Ya que el mensaje `"Falta el carácter coma (,) por favor ingreselo:"` se repite una sola vez, se que se debe de volver un bucle, pero no me ha salido bien el comando la cual es `while`. Por favor ayúdenme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debe estar dentro del bucle while,  intente usted lo siguiente:

```
String toList="";
System.out.println("Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: ");          
while(true){
    toList= br.readLine();
    if( (toList == null) || (toList.trim().equals("")) ){
        System.out.println("El campo que ingreso esta vacio, vuelva a ingresarlo:");
        continue;
    }
    if(!toList.contains(",")){
        System.out.println("Falta el caracter coma (,) por favor ingreselo:");
        continue;                   
    }
    CorreoUtilBuffereader1.Lista(toList);
    break;
}
```

Claro si usted gusta que se vea cada mensaje por separado, caso contrario la respuesta de alanfcm es suficiente.

Answer (score 2):

Basado en la pregunta:

> [Ayuda en una lista en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161051/ayuda-en-una-lista-en-java/)

Te dejo la siguiente respuesta:

```
public static void Lista(String textList) {
        String[] stList = textList.split(",");
        Arrays.asList(stList);
        String lista = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < stList.length; i++) {
            if (stList[i] == null || stList[i].trim().equals("")) {
                System.out.println("El campo que ingreso esta vacio, vuelva a ingresarlo");
                lista = teclado.nextLine();
                //Se valida si el campo no contiene la ,
                while(!lista.contains(",")){
                    System.out.println("El campo no contiene (,) vuelva a ingresarlo");
                    lista = teclado.nextLine();
                }
                stList[i]=lista;
                i = i-1;
            } else {
                System.out.println(stList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
String toList="";
System.out.println("Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: ");          
            toList= br.readLine();
            while((toList == null) || (toList.trim().equals(""))  || !(toList.contains(","))){
                  System.out.println("El campo que ingreso esta vacio, o falta el caracter coma(,) vuelva a ingresarlo:");
                  toList= br.readLine();
            }
            CorreoUtilBuffereader1.Lista(toList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer uso de un bucle `do-while` para validar lo ingresado por el usuario. Con este bucle lograrás hacer que se ejecute por lo menos una vez y que si en la validación de lo ingresado por el usuario resulta que debe ingresar información de nuevo, pues que se repita el ciclo. Además puedes hacer uso de variables booleanas para almacenar el resultado de las validaciones.

El código propuesto con `do-while` es el siguiente:

```
String toList="";
Boolean estaVacio = false;
Boolean contieneComa = false;

System.out.println("Escribe un String para convertirlo a List: ");

do
{
    toList = br.readLine();

    if (estaVacio = (toList == null || toList.trim().equals(""))
        System.out.println("El campo que ingreso esta vacio, vuelva a ingresarlo:");
    else if (contieneComa = toList.contains(","))
        CorreoUtilBuffereader1.Lista(toList);
    else
        System.out.println("Falta el caracter coma (,) por favor ingreselo:");

} while (estaVacio || !contieneComa);
```

De esta manera permite primero que el usuario ingrese una cadena de texto y lo almacenará en la variable `toList`, luego validará si está vacío o es nulo y almacenará el resultado en la variable `estaVacio`, a continuación validará si la cadena ingresada contiene algun caracter coma y el resultado lo almacenará en la variable `conteienComa`, en ambos casos se imprime un mensaje de error. En el caso que todo sea correcto, ejecutará la línea `CorreoUtilBuffereader1.Lista(toList);` y saldrá del bucle.

Al finalizar todo, el bucle `do-while` evalúa los los booleanos anteriores y estos determinan si se vuelve a ejecutar. Es decir, luego de haber validado, si al finalizar el bucle la cadena está vacía o no contiene coma, entonces se vuelve a repetir.